# Adding specific items in list [x] for separate lists after importing .txt file in Python

Tags: python

I am importing labdata.txt in the code that follows.  For statements, such as for `i` in values: will add each variable in a given parameter.  For each set of parameters, e.g., [1, 3, 4,] [3, 5, 7], [67, 56, 56], my goal is to add [1] + [3] + [67] for example.  Then to obtain the average of these three items.

The part that is unclear is how to take `x = values[:1]` and then somehow have it add that variable for `x` in the different parameters like explained above.

Here is the code so far:

```
    lab_data = open("labdata.txt", "r") #import text
    x = 0 # initialize variable
    y = 0 # initialize variable
    for aline in lab_data:
        values = aline.split()
        values = [int (u) for u in values]
        print (values)
        x = values[:1]
        y = values[1:2]
        print (x)
        #print (y)
        average = 0
        ui = 0
        other = 0
        bs = 0
        # print (sum(values[:1]))
    for z in values[:1]:
        other = (sum(values[:1]))
        bs = bs + other
        print (bs)
```

`#print (sum(values[:1]))
    ui = ui + z
average = ui / len(values)#this just gives the avg of x
print (average)
</pre>`

Comment: question is very unclear.

Comment: could you provide a sample labdata.txt?

Answer (score 2):

Let me answer this very unclear question
I assume your question is: *how to get an average from three different lists*

```
lst1 = [1, 3, 4]
lst2 = [3, 5, 7]
lst3 = [67, 56, 56]

avg1 = sum([lst1[0],lst2[0],lst3[0]]) / 3
avg2 = sum([lst1[1],lst2[1],lst3[1]]) / 3
avg3 = sum([lst1[2],lst2[2],lst3[2]]) / 3

print avg1,avg2,avg3
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted for what reason, but I'm sad.

Comment: Is it a generalized solution?

Comment: trying to help OP to understand what pieces are needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python3, you can use `statistics.mean` with zip:

```
lst1 = [1, 3, 4]
lst2 = [3, 5, 7]
lst3 = [67, 56, 56]

from statistics import mean

a, b, c = map(mean, zip(lst1, lst2, lst3))

print(a, b, c)
```

For python2 create your own mean function:

```
from itertools import imap, izip

def mean(x):
    return sum(x) / float(len(x))

a, b, c = imap(mean, izip(lst1, lst2, lst3))

print(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Letting each list have the same length, this is my solution:

```
lst1 = [1, 2, 3]
lst2 = [3, 4, 5]
lst3 = [3, 2, 1]

# list "lst" will contain the results for every index
lst =[]

for i in range(len(lst1)):
    lst.append(lst1[i]/3 + lst2[i]/3 + lst3[i]/3)

print lst
```

Comment: might wanna do `len(lst1)` instead of `3`, if you wanna play the 'generalized solution' game?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is something like:

```
lab_data = open("labdata.txt", "r") #import text
int_data = [[int(val) for val in line.split()] for line in lines]

def mean(args): return float(sum(args))/len(args)
means = []
for i in range(0, len(int_data[0])):
    means.append(mean([row[i] for row in int_data]))
```